# Problem starting JACK server "Jack Server is not running or cannot be started"

Tags: sound, jack, daw

I haven't been able to get JACK to work despite googling and reading on forums. Please help me to get JACK to work. I am attaching the message log of JACK Control here.

```
02:15:40.109 Patchbay deactivated.
02:15:40.117 Statistics reset.
02:15:40.123 ALSA connection change.
02:15:40.147 D-BUS: Service is available (org.jackaudio.service aka jackdbus).
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
02:15:40.169 ALSA connection graph change.
02:15:43.877 D-BUS: JACK server could not be started. Sorry
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
Mon Dec  8 02:15:43 2014: Starting jack server...
Mon Dec  8 02:15:43 2014: JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
Mon Dec  8 02:15:43 2014: ERROR: Cannot lock down 82274202 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
Mon Dec  8 02:15:43 2014: ERROR: cannot register object path "/org/freedesktop/ReserveDevice1/Audio0": A handler is already registered for /org/freedesktop/ReserveDevice1/Audio0
Mon Dec  8 02:15:43 2014: ERROR: Failed to acquire device name : Audio0 error : A handler is already registered for /org/freedesktop/ReserveDevice1/Audio0
Mon Dec  8 02:15:43 2014: ERROR: Audio device hw:0 cannot be acquired...
Mon Dec  8 02:15:43 2014: ERROR: Cannot initialize driver
Mon Dec  8 02:15:43 2014: ERROR: JackServer::Open failed with -1
Mon Dec  8 02:15:43 2014: ERROR: Failed to open server
Mon Dec  8 02:15:45 2014: Saving settings to "/home/rythem/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
02:15:47.373 Could not connect to JACK server as client. - Overall operation failed. - Unable to connect to server. Please check the messages window for more info.
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
```

Answer (score 12):

First you need to kill the existing pulseaudio process, start the jack_control process and re-start the pulseaudio process.

Please use the below commands:

```
pulseaudio --kill

jack_control start

jack_control exit

pulseaudio --start
```

Comment: "jack_control start" outputs the error: "DBus exception: org.jackaudio.Error.Generic: Failed to open server"

Answer (score 2):

Try using `pasuspender` with qjackctl. Like this:

`pasuspender qjackctl`

It should "pause" pulseaudio while qjackctl runs and "respawn" pulseaudio when qjackctl is terminated.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to run Jack with real-time priorities, and Jack does not configure that by default in Ubuntu.  There are two ways to solve this:

**1)  Don't use realtime priorities.**

By CLI you can start Jack without realtime, using `jackd -r &` - see `man jackd` for more details.

If you `sudo apt install qjackctl` to can run the GUI "Qjackctl", and in the 'Setup' section unclick "Realtime"

[image]

**2)  Setup realtime for Jack**, as decribed in http://www.jackaudio.org/faq/linux_rt_config.html

Open a terminal and enter

```
sudo nano /etc/security/limits.d/99-realtime.conf
```

Add the lines

```
@realtime   -  rtprio     99
@realtime   -  memlock    unlimited
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to save and exit the file.

Create and add yourself to the 'realtime' group:

```
sudo groupadd realtime
sudo usermod -a -G realtime yourUserID
```

Logout and back in.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing above works try setting the `Interface` in the Setup GUI to `hw:PCH`

Answer (score -1):

in otions connect the correct input ,output devices
in my motherboard gigabyte F2A88X-D3HP with on board sound card jack work only if selected frame rate as 192000
i hope this work for you!

Comment: The who and what? I can't parse your answer. Could you please [edit] it to improve the syntax? Thanks.