# Error initializing Jack audio server

Tags: sound, jack

I wanted to start jack server with the command

```
sudo jackd -r -d alsa -r 44100
```

But I got the following errors :

```
JACK server starting in non-realtime mode
self-connect-mode is "Don't restrict self connect requests"
audio_reservation_init
Acquire audio card Audio0
creating alsa driver ... hw:0|hw:0|1024|2|44100|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
ALSA: Cannot open PCM device alsa_pcm for playback. Falling back to capture-only mode
Released audio card Audio0
audio_reservation_finish
Cannot initialize driver
JackServer::Open failed with -1
Failed to open server
```

I tried the solutions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1124377/1001338) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/777136/1001338) .Those Didn't work for me.

I use jackd version 1.9 with linux kernel 5.3 in ubuntu bionic.

Answer (score 3):

**Setting the device explicitly to hw:PCH helps**

Firstly, prevent pulseaudio from restarting ...

`/etc/pulse/client.conf`

`~/.config/pulse/client.conf`

`~/.pulse/client.conf`

Stop pulseaudio

`pulseaudio --kill`

In QjackCtl (graphics mode) setup ...

**Set to alsa**

**Set hw:PCH (try all)**

**Set it to realtime (try both)**

**In the next tab set "execute script after startup" with**

`pacmd set-default-sink jack_out`

**Save and start the server now**

Start pulseaudio ...

`pulseaudio --start`